# failed: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in header value, Tomcat server8

Tags: html, tomcat, utf-8, websocket, video-streaming

I am using tomcat 8.0 as my server for a Websocket application.
But when I try to establish a connection ws = new Websocket(.....);
it throws the following error:
failed: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in header value

Anybody has come around this or knows how to fix it ??

PS am using eclipse as platform and chrome 33.0+

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>face detection</title>

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <video id="live" width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay"
            style="display: inline;"></video>
        <canvas width="320" id="canvas" height="240" style="display: inline;"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img id="target" style="display: inline;" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var video = $("#live").get()[0];
        var canvas = $("#canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.get()[0].getContext('2d');
        var options = {
            "video" : true
        };
          var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/FaceDetection/livevideo");
            ws.onopen = function () {
                      console.log("Openened connection to websocket");
            }

            /**ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
                var target = document.getElementById("target");
                url = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(msg.data);
                target.onload = function() {
                    window.webkitURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                };
                target.src = url;
            }*/

        // use the chrome specific GetUserMedia function
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(options, function(stream) {
            video.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("Unable to get video stream!")
        })

         timer = setInterval(
            function () {
                ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
                var data = canvas.get()[0].toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
                newblob = dataURItoBlob(data);
                ws.send(newblob);
            }, 150);

    function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {

                var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

                // separate out the mime component
                var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

                // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
                var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
                var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
                for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
                }

            // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
            var bb = new Blob([ab]);
            //bb.append(ab);
            return bb;
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Gettin error at the following line:
 var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/FaceDetection/livevideo");

Comment: can you show the complete code for the creation of that WS and in which line you get the exception?

Comment: And the server side code is ... ?

Comment: Thanks guys ive got it figured..
This problem exists in tomcat 8.0.0 but it is fixed in tomcat 8.0.3 so ive used this instead :) Thanks for replies anyway